# ASP.NET - Don't want page to refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I have this function, and I don't want the page to refresh when I click on Add Button. Can you help me?

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="autores">Autores</label>
            <textarea runat="server" class="form-control" rows="1" id="autores"></textarea>
            <asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="addAutor();" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-default" AutoPostback=false  />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <table id="lista" contenteditable>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Autores</strong></td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
        <script>
            function addAutor() {
                var table = document.getElementById("lista");
                var row = table.insertRow(1);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
                cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

OK! So...i also try to do this:

```
<table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td>Row1 cell1</td>
                <td>Row1 cell2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row2 cell1</td>
                <td>Row2 cell2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row3 cell1</td>
                <td>Row3 cell2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var row = table.insertRow(0);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
                cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
            }
        </script>
```

with a html button...but it still not work, because it adds the content to the table, but the page reloads, and the new content disapears.

Comment: `OnClientClick="return addAutor();"` should already make a difference

Comment: why are you using an asp button if you don't want it posted back to the server?  that's kinda the point of asp...  why not just use a simple html button?  also - if you still have trouble - take a look at event.preventDefault() in javascript.

Comment: @doxick What i want my code to do is to add a new row to a table. But when the page reload, the new contents of the table disapears. I want this to happen on the interface, and not to make a call to the server

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:button id="Button1"
      text="Submit"
      onclick="addAutor();" 
      usesubmitbehavior="false"
      runat="server"/>
```

Set [usesubmitbehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) to false to change the button from submit to button type

I see your sample working fine, may be add type="button"

```js
        
            function myFunction() {
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var row = table.insertRow(0);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
                cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
            }
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td>Row1 cell1</td>
                <td>Row1 cell2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row2 cell1</td>
                <td>Row2 cell2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row3 cell1</td>
                <td>Row3 cell2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: What i want my code to do is to add a new row to a table. But when the page reload, the new contents of the table disapears.
I want this to happen on the interface, and not to make a call to the server.